# What is the meaning of "bigamystery"?

Tags: meaning, nouns, portmanteau-words

Searching on Google yields nothing about this word's meaning but does yield some quotes in which it is used. I came across it in the following quote:

> Why a man would want a wife is a big mystery to some people. Why a man would want *two* wives is a bigamystery.

No dictionary I own has this word. Every text editor I type this in paints it red.

Comment: Probably means **a bigger mystery** based on the context.

Comment: *bigamystery* is the way some Italians talk when speaking English. They add a vowel sound after words or syllables that end in certain consonants because Italian doesn't have many words that end in consonants. Consider https://youtu.be/sFacWGBJ_cs

Comment: That's an absolutely brilliant pun.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - And it needs to be noted that it's a punmanteau.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a joke. *Bigamy* means illegally married to more than one person. So

> *biga**my*** + ***my***stery = *biga**my**stery*

A **my**stery as to why anyone would want to be in two marriages at once.

Comment: You beat me to it (didn't see your post until I joined the community)

Comment: @Tensigh Only by a minute. Welcome to the site. I do type fairly fast for a sleep-reversed person.

Comment: Why he would marry once is a 'big mystery', in addition to the answer above 'bigamystery' *sounds like* 'bigger mystery'.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this is a form of *pun*.

Comment: @Spagirl -- "a biga", in the US, is a common way of pronouncing "a big" when using a (bad) fake Italian accent.

Comment: @HotLicks It's within spitting distance of how 'bigger' sounds in most varieties of English. One wife, big mistake, two wives  /ˈbɪɡɚ/ mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a play on words: combining "big mystery" with "bigamy". Actually, that's what it sounded like to me when I saw the question listed.